# If I try to use a non-spell-slotted spell as a contingent spell, does it expend a slot anyway?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

> You cast that spell, called the contingent spell, as part of casting contingency, *expending spell slots for both*
>   [*emphasis* mine]

If the spell I cast (say from a magic item or a racial trait) does not require a spell slot usually, does casting that spell as a contingent spell end up expending a spell slot as a result of *contingency*?

Here's an example of this practice:

1. I'm a Duergar Wizard
2. I cast *contingency* selecting *enlarge/reduce* from Duergar Magic as my contingent spell.

What is step 3?
Does *contingency* fail since the contingent spell doesnt expend a spell slot?
Do I expend a 2nd level slot (from the *contingency* description) and the spell works normally?
Does *contingency* work even without expending a spell slot?
Can I not chose my non-slotted-spell in the first place?
Something else?

---

*Note:*

*I believe this is a separate question from [If you have the ability to cast a spell without a spell slot can you cast that spell using a spell slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102875/if-you-have-the-ability-to-cast-a-spell-without-a-spell-slot-can-you-cast-that-s) as I may not be casting the spell using the slot but the slot is merely expended as part of the effect of* contingency.

Comment: Are you assuming that you CAN use a no-spell-slotted spell for *Contingency*?

Comment: @NautArch i tried not to by including the "rhe spell fails" option. If you want to [edit] to make it more inconclusive feel free (I made a small edit)

Comment: As it stands, you've got several questions in here. I think you may need to focus on each one separately.

Comment: Related (probably): https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124689/can-contingency-be-used-with-a-spell-cast-from-an-ioun-stone

Comment: @Medix2 Definitely related, and my answer presents a potential roadblock to this question.

Comment: Perhaps simply edit out the possible answers you've given and see what ones people come up with.

Comment: @Medicx I include suggested answers as a method to demonstrate my train of thought. That's why I put "something else?" For things I haven't considered

Comment: Closed as too broad at the request of the author, who intends to split it in two: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45215250#45215250

Answer (score 1):

### No: it would not expend a slot

When the spell says "expending spell slots for both" it's natural to ask the question "which spell slots"? Do you have to spend a 6th level spell slot twice, since contingency is a 6th level spell? Certainly not: if that were the case you couldn't use Contingency until two levels after you learned it (since 11th level full casters  only have one 6th level spell slot).

The natural conclusion is that you need to expend *whatever level spell slot the spell usually requires*. In your case, that requirement is no spell slot at all because the enlarge/reduce ability takes something other than a spell slot. Thus, you could cast "enlarge/reduce" with contingency, without needing to spend a spell slot (since you don't need to spend a slot to cast it normally).

As further evidence of this, consider the fact that there is [consensus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115652/can-the-contingency-spell-trigger-a-cantrip) 
that you can use contingency **with a cantrip**. Thus, the text stating that you will be "expending spell slots for both" does not restrict this spell to spells that require spell slots (nor does it force spells to require spell slots when they normally do not).

Comment: Are you saying that a non-spell-slotted spell cannot be used with *Contingency*?

Comment: Whereas I agree this is the intent I believe more sources would go along way to supporting it.